# Testing equality of doubles in R - weird behaviour

Tags: r

First, I will preface this question by saying that I know it is a bad idea to test equality of doubles using `==` and that i should instead use `isTRUE(all.equal())`, but I've encountered some strange behaviour that is not the result of rounding:

The setup:

```
> a <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6)
> b <- a - 0.3
 [1] -0.1 0.1 0.3
> c <- abs(b)
 [1] 0.1 0.1 0.3
```

Now onto the strange behaviour:

```
which(a == 0.4)  # This works fine.
which(b == 0.1)  # integer(0) - no good.
which(b == 0.3)  # But this works fine?
which(c == 0.3)  # Also fine
which(c == 0.1)  # integer(0) - no good.
c[1] == c[2]     # FALSE
```

I'm at a loss as to why it works fine in some cases but not others?

Comment: Turns out my understanding of floating points was still wrong!

Comment: FAQ 7.31! http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f